# ASP 3.0 consider PRINTs and Warnings from SQL Server as an ERROR

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, error-handling

In my ASP page I put an "on error resume next" and in the end of file I do

```
If err.number <> 0 then
response.write "error"
end if
```

But the ASP page is considering PRINT and WARNINGs messages from a SQL Server procedure as an ERROR and enter in IF condition.

Why this happens in some servers and another one it dont?

Tks.

Answer (score 0):

It probably happens on different servers because your setting for `SET ANSI_WARNINGS` is `ON` in some cases and `OFF` in others. You can see this by investigating `sys.dm_exec_sessions`. Since having different settings for this and other options from different applications can lead to vastly different performance characteristics, it's in your best interest to set these options explicitly and consistently across all of your applications.

Comment: But the PRINT command is not a Warning message. Even if my TSQL dont shows any warning message but a PRINT, the ASP will consider it an ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

err.number <> 0 is only directly AFTER the statements which crashes...

so:

```
ii = 1/0
xx= 3
if err.number <> then
    response.write "This will never be printed..."
end if
```

Comment: Yes, because there is an error on code, if err.number <> 0 ... And then the message is print.